# how to filter arrays whose length is greater than zero among multiple array using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to append multiple arrays using jquery extend. I wanted to add only those arrays whose length is greater than zero to the jquery extend. Can any one please help?

```
personarray['Person']=person;
providerarray['Provider']=provider;
researcherarray['Researcher']=researcher;

var dataStr;

dataStr = JSON.stringify($.extend(true, personarray, providerarray, researcherarray));
```

instead of adding all the three arrays, I wanted to filter only the non-empty arrays and append them.

For example, if person array is empty then I get the datastr as -

```
{"Profile Id":1234,"Person":[],"Provider":[{"table name":"Provider","unique id":"0","field name":"ProSalary","field value":"$320,800"}],"Researcher":[{"table name":"Researcher","unique id":"0","field name":"ProSalary","field value":"$320,800"}]}
```

Instead I should be able to get it as below i.e person array removed-

```
{"Profile Id":1234,"Provider":[{"table name":"Provider","unique id":"0","field name":"ProSalary","field value":"$320,800"}],"Researcher":[{"table name":"Researcher","unique id":"0","field name":"ProSalary","field value":"$320,800"}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ternary operator to check that array is empty or not. here is sample.

```
var personarray={};
personarray['Person']=[];

var providerarray={};
providerarray['Provider']=[1,2,3];

var researcherarray={};
researcherarray['Researcher']=['A','B'];

var dataStr = JSON.stringify($.extend(true, (personarray.Person.length == 0 ? {} : personarray), providerarray, researcherarray));

console.log(dataStr)
```

It will give this output

```
{"Provider":[1,2,3],"Researcher":["A","B"]}
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/a868hwz2/)**

Note: I have applied check only for **personarray**, you can do the same for other objects as well.